# install certificates

Tags: certificates

I received a .crt certificate to install on my new galaxy tab 10.1.
How do I install it?

I see that I can "install from USB storage" but couldn't figure out where this storage is.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/70123/18559) to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/61540/18559).

Answer (score 1):

From http://sknetlog.blogspot.com/2011/03/digital-certificate-installation-on.html

1. Save your .p12 or .cer certificate to external SD card in root
   directoy.
2. Navigate "Home" --> "Applications" --> "Settings"
3. Select "Location and Security"
4. Under "Credential storage" have the first
   item "Use secure credentials" selected / checked
5. Select "Install encrypted certificates from SD card" and it would pop up the name of
   the certificate file found in the SD card
   6 . Provide the certificate import password if any.