# self-signed certificate install claims success, but android acts as if cert isn't there

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, certificates, https

I am trying to install the self-signed certificate for my web server in Android 4.3. I have the .crt file in the root of the SD card (which is actually emulated as I have no SD card in the slot).

To install the certificate I go to Setting -> General -> Security -> Credential Storage -> Install from device storage.

I get a dialog box showing the name of the certificate (the filename  minus the .crt extension) which I can modify (but don't), a "used for" pull down with "VPN and apps" selected and text at the bottom of the dialog which informs "Package contains: one user certificate". Everything looks okay, so I click "Ok". The dialog goes away and a toast message pops up with "[name] installed".

However if I immediately go to "Trusted credentials and select "User" there is nothing there! The new cert is also not under "System" but I would not expect it there.  If I go to a browser after this and try going to my web site, I still get the warning that the site's certificate is not trusted. I have also tried rebooting, but it doesn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong? The complete lack of error messages isn't helpful.  Is it possible my certificate is in the wrong format? I have tried using the .crt file in the server's ssl directory and I have tried converting it to DER format.

Update: I read somewhere that Android requires certificates to be in p12 format, so I converted the Apache2 certificate to p12 using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey server.key -in server.crt -out ~/server.p12
```

I then repeated the above steps, got the same success message, and then proceeded to still not see the certificate in the user credentials and I still get the untrusted certificate error from the mobile browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem getting Android to really install the certificate, until I found [this site](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html) which describes a method that worked for me. It boils down to the following steps:

1. Create a private key and public x509 certificate with v3_req extensions and enabled as a CA:

   `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/my_site.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/my_site.crt -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca`
2. Convert the certificate to DER format, which is understood by Android:

   `sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/my_site.crt -outform der -out my_site.der.crt`
3. Use any method to get the `my_site.der.crt` to your Android device - I found it easy to just have the file hosted by my web server and download it via the Android browser, which then automatically lets you install it.

Although I would've liked step 1 to be broken into two (1a. generation of private key and 1b. generation of public certificate), I didn't invest too much time investigating how to do that. Please let me know in a comment if you found a way that works, thanks.

(Rather than add a comment, I feel this really belongs as part of the answer for future reference, so I am editing it in. --Michael)

Instead of creating a certificate enabled as a CA, I created a self-signed CA and then re-signed my existing key/csr with the new CA.  Then I added the self-signed CA to Android and voila!  It worked!

Generating the self-signed CA:

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -days 3650 -out rootCA.pem
```

Re-signing an existing CSR I had from creation of the key from the

```
openssl x509 -req -in existing.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out existing.crt -days 3649
```

Now using a modified form of your second command I converted the CA certificate to DER form:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/ssl/rootCA.pem -outform der -out ~/rootCA.der.crt
```

The great thing about this is, any additional untrusted certificates that are now re-signed with the new self-signed CA will now be trusted on any device than has the new CA installed without needing to install anything else.  This doesn't exactly solve the problem of trusting sites you have no control over, but it might make it easier if you have any influence over (say) your IT department for an internal server or something.

Comment: I already have the certificate I need to install, so I tried step 2 and it still is not showing up in User Trusted Credentials after it claims to succeed in installing, and Chrome still displays the "untrusted site" error after restarting.

Comment: Could there be something about the v3_req extension and enabled as CA that the certificate is required to have for Android to use it?  If so, is there a command that I can use to take an existing certificate and add that information to it, as I don't have control over all the certs I want to install.

Comment: To answer the first half of my previous question, I read the page you had linked, and it appears that the problem is that Android refuses to install self-signed certificates (but not self-signed CAs).  This seems to be un(der)-documented, and the fact that Android pretends to install makes it even worse.  But the question remains, if I have a self-signed cert that I don't have control over, is there some way to "CA"-ify it so I can install it?

Comment: @Michael, that is why I said in my answer that I'd like to break up step 1 so it could be used for already existing certificates. Since I only needed it for my own server, I was fortunate enough to be able to use the steps as they are. But I totally agree with you, this is one of the really nasty issues of Android, especially because there doesn't seem to be any clear documentation on that... I spent many hours searching and trial-and-error until I found that link.

Comment: @I hope you don't mind, I'm going to edit your answer to include my solution, rather than including it in the comments, as it really belong as part of the answer.

Comment: +1 I don't mind at all - because it will enable future readers to re-sign additional certificates. Thanks for investigating and finding this significant improvement! I might edit the answer slightly for clarity later.

Comment: I don't get it how the existing.csr signing request is generated. I think this is the last missing point for a complete step by step tutorial.

Comment: Not working any longer on Android 4.4. Again claiming success even telling that certificate is installed on repeated attempt, but it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @wie5Ooma: I am using the certificate I created via the first method (steps labelled 1,2,3 above) on my Android 4.4.4 (Cyanogenmod). It complains at startup about "your device is being monitored" but apart from that, it works just fine.

Comment: @FriendFX My android 4.4.2 (non rooted) pretends to import the certificate like I said before but does not store it. CADroid refuses to import the certificate and complains about the identity in the CN field. I'm using the IP address in the CN field which might contribute to this.

Comment: @wie5Ooma My 4.4.4 isn't rooted either. I'd suggest investigating the CN field problem and if that doesn't help, have a look at [this site](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html) (which is where I got the info for this answer from), maybe there is some corner case I have missed. Let us know how you go!

Comment: I see I didn't respond to this. I solved the problem. CAdroid is just plain stupid and tries to import the server certificate, not the CA certificate so I imported it manually.

Comment: After trying A THOUSAND things... It was the extensions which were missing. So, creating the cert and key using `-reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca` finally did the trick. At least 6 hours. I swear. Thanks!!

Comment: Old comment @cguenther, but "Re-signing an existing CSR I had from creation of the key from the" is confusing since instructions for creating existing.csr aren't mentioned. However, you can create it from existing.crt and existing.key files using "openssl x509 -x509toreq -in my_site.crt -out existing.csr -signkey my_site.key"